# How to show the total values of rows in a Matrix with number value having my columns values as percentage

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I've started to manage PowerBi from a couple of weeks so i'm a little bit confused about some things.

**My problem is that i need a Matrix in my dashboard with percent values but i want the total in number value because the total of a percent of row shows me always 100% and i dont know about the number i'm working**

This is my Matrix with percentage values

[image: This is my Matrix with percentage values]

This is how i want the total of row returns me but with the columns values ins percentage

[image: This is how i want the total of row returns me but with the columns values ins percentage]

I've tried to make a measure counting the values

`COUNT(OPSRespuestas[answer])`

After that turn off the total of rows and add this measure to the values in my matrix but this is what i get

This is my table after trying add a measure with the total

[image: This is my table after trying add a measure with the total]

It returns me the total for each of the columns and not the total of all my rows.

These are the tables i'm working with

This my top header values

[image: This my top header values]

This is my left header values

[image: This is my left header values]

The answer column is what i need to count

[image: The answer column is what i need to count]

This is my relationship between this 3 tables although i have many more intermediate table aside from this 3 as you're going to see in the next picture:

My relationship tables

[image: My relationship tables]

So finally what i need is that this matrix shows me the total of answer in percentage for each of departments and group of questions and then show me total by department but with number value

Comment: Turn off "Total". Instead, write a DAX measure that calculates whatever you need for the total. Add the measure to the matrix.

Comment: I've just tried what you told me and i made i measure, i turned off the subtotal of rows and i added my measure to values in the Matrix but it returns me the Total for each of the columns

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing has to do with context. Each row is seen as it own total population hence the 100% total. Each column in this row is evaluated against the total of that row to provide a percentage value.

In addition to adding a custom measure to replace the total, you could also consider computing a percentage against the grand total of all dimensions. This means that each cell gets evaluated against the the total of all rows and columns. In this ways the cell value would change compared to your first table but the row total does not evaluate to 100% anymore.

```
SUM ( [Value] ) / CALCULATE ( SUM ( [Value] ) ; ALL ( 'Your Table' ) )
```

Comment: Where i should add that measure?? because i'm doing it over values in the matrix and it doesn't work

Comment: Should do the trick in the values box but I didn't know you were using a count. This should work better `COUNTA( 'Your table'[Value] ) / CALCULATE( COUNTA( 'Your table'[Value] ) ; ALL( 'Your table' ) )`

Comment: i dont know the reason but i tried this with my answers table and it results me 0 in each row.

Comment: Can you share a picture of your model so I can have a look at your relationships? It probably requires a little refinement considering you are using multiple tables to generate the matrix, is that correct?

Comment: Yes i'm using 3 tables for this exercise i share the relationship. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for sharing, looks like a rather complex model. Are you using any of the inactive relationships in certain calculations? Is this the measure you made from my pseudo code: `COUNTA ( 'OPSRespuestas'[Answer] ) / CALCULATE ( COUNTA ( 'OPSRespuestas'[Answer] ) ; ALL ( 'OPSRespuestas' ) )` ?

Comment: Yes i've just done that measure and it doesnt work. I'm just using the 3 tables i marked

Comment: Hmmm, something else must be going on then because I do get the desired result in a assumed simulation of your above model. What happens if you both both the count and the percentage measure in the same table? Although you are explicitly using only 3 tables you implicitly use the tables that link them up through their relationships as well. Probably the cause of your problem is somewhere in there.